# Filter on log levels in Firebug

Tags: logging, firebug

The excellent Firebug offers log functions such as `console.error()` and `console.info()`. However, the tabs (or pills?) in Firebug select only the *exact* same level. That is, when I click on ‘Errors’ I get all the errors (that’s good), but when I click on ‘Warnings’ I get all the warning *only*, but *not* the errors – and that’s bad.

Is this a bug or a feature? Is there an option? Shouldn’t I be able to see all the warnings and errors while *not* being bothered with debug stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no option to just show warnings and errors. Therefore I created an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4621) for allowing to select multiple filters at the same time some time ago in the Firebug issue tracker.

Comment: … and apparenty it was fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, I finally implemented it since I already wanted that feature for a long time.